# Referencing a module / script when using npm and grunt

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, bower

I'm looking into npm, grunt and bower, and I've made my first task which looks like this.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';',
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js'],
            dest: 'dist/scripts.js',
        },
    },
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

};
```

I was wondering if there's an easier/better way of adding the scripts. So that instead of typing the whole path you could just do `src: [jquery, 'handlebars'],`

and if bower is of any use regarding this?

Thank you.

Comment: Would [bower](https://bower.io/) be of any help?

Comment: I'm not sure how Bower would help in this situation - you'd still end up with path names in your config, they'd just point into Bower's folder instead of NPM's.